# Replacing all repeated elements within a column with NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, na

How do I replace all repeated elements within a column with [na](/questions/tagged/na) in [r](/questions/tagged/r)? This is an example subset of the data I am working with:

```
> df.1
         V1      V2      V3      V4
X1    4D+44  18D+30 125D+44   4D+48
X2     NONE    NONE 125D+44    NONE
X3     NONE    NONE 125D+44    NONE
X4  29D+139 18D+124 125D+44  4D+133
X5  29D+139  5D+164 125D+44    NONE
X6  30D+174  9D+194    NONE    NONE
X7   6D+227  4D+225    NONE 39D+217
X8     NONE    NONE    NONE 39D+217
X9   4D+285    NONE    NONE    NONE
X10    NONE    NONE    NONE    NONE
```

Within in each column I want to replace repeated elements with `NA`. For example I want `V1` to look like this:

```
4D+44 NA NA NA NA 30D+174 6D+227 NA 4D+285 NA
```

The closest I can get to the result is through using `duplicated()`

```
> df.1$V1[duplicated(df.1$V1)] <- NA
> df[df == "NONE"] <- NA
```

But it results in `V1` looking like this, keeping the first value of the repeated elements.

```
4D+44 NA NA 29D+139 NA 30D+174 6D+227 NA 4D+285 NA
```

Is there a way to recognize and replace all repeated elements?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: In future, please look to `dput` for making a reproducible copy of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to create a logical index and use that to `replace` each of the columns with the `NA`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) 
       replace(x, duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE),  NA))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate_all(~ replace(., duplicated(.)|duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE), NA))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("4D+44", "NONE", "NONE", "29D+139", "29D+139", 
"30D+174", "6D+227", "NONE", "4D+285", "NONE"), V2 = c("18D+30", 
"NONE", "NONE", "18D+124", "5D+164", "9D+194", "4D+225", "NONE", 
"NONE", "NONE"), V3 = c("125D+44", "125D+44", "125D+44", "125D+44", 
"125D+44", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE"), V4 = c("4D+48", 
"NONE", "NONE", "4D+133", "NONE", "NONE", "39D+217", "39D+217", 
"NONE", "NONE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X1", "X2", 
"X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"))
```